# How to config rsyslog with a filename not static

Tags: rsyslog

I need to monitor a log file that rotates every day in the same location. The format of the file is: filename.log.YY-MM-DD

To config rsyslog, I use wildcard to map filename.log.*, but I don't want to review old logs, just the actual day.

I tried to use date command in File parameter but its not recognized. Also with a variable is not recognized.

```
input(type="imfile"
  File="/var/log/filename.log.*"
  Tag="logstore""
  Severity="info"
  Facility="local4")
```

I expected just log the last filename.log.today, not all filename.log.*